# Block invoke crash in iOS 12

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am writing code that block invoke itself in iOS, unfortunately, i got an error:

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10).

This is my code:

```
__block NSInteger i = 0;
void (^block)() = ^() {
    if (i == 0) {
        i ++;
        block();
    }
};
block();
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I found write like this : __block void (^block)() = ^() { .  It works fine! I don't know the reason.

Comment: You should have this warning: "Block pointer variable 'block' is uninitialized when captured by block" that might point out the issue.